# How to calculate quantum circuit with given quantum state?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit

I have task to calculate this quantum circuit
[image]

Where psi is:

```
x1 = 5
x2 = 1
r = x1 * x1 + x2 * x2
a = np.sqrt(1 + 2*r)
psi = [0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, 1/(np.sqrt(2)*a), 0, x1/(np.sqrt(2)*a), x2/(np.sqrt(2)*a), x1/(np.sqrt(2)*a), x2/(np.sqrt(2)*a), 0, 0]
```

I am doing this type of code:

```
circ = QuantumCircuit(4)

circ.h(0)

meas = QuantumCircuit(4, 4)
meas.barrier(range(4))
# map the quantum measurement to the classical bits
meas.measure(range(4), range(4))

# The Qiskit circuit object supports composition using
# the addition operator.
qc = circ + meas
qc.initialize(psi, 4)
#drawing the circuit
backend_sim = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')

# Execute the circuit on the qasm simulator.
# We've set the number of repeats of the circuit
# to be 1024, which is the default.
qc.draw('mpl')

job_sim = execute(qc, backend_sim, shots=1000)

# Grab the results from the job.
result_sim = job_sim.result()
counts = result_sim.get_counts(qc)
print(counts)
```

But getting this error:

```
CircuitError: 'Index out of range.'
```

If I change qc.initialize like this:

```
qc.initialize(psi, 3)
```

I get this:

```
QiskitError: 'Initialize parameter vector has 16 elements, therefore expects 4 qubits. However, 1 were provided.'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](https://render.githubusercontent.com/view/ipynb?color_mode=light&commit=daeac74ba3b5e021c89397cd8465585f0f49e121&enc_url=68747470733a2f2f7261772e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f5169736b69742f7169736b69742d7475746f7269616c732f646165616337346261336235653032316338393339376364383436353538356630663439653132312f7475746f7269616c732f63697263756974732f335f73756d6d6172795f6f665f7175616e74756d5f6f7065726174696f6e732e6970796e62&nwo=Qiskit%2Fqiskit-tutorials&path=tutorials%2Fcircuits%2F3_summary_of_quantum_operations.ipynb&repository_id=99244384&repository_type=Repository#Arbitrary-initialization-), for initialization, you should make it as a list. Hence for your case, since it only uses 4 qubits, you could write

```
qc.initialize(psi, [0,1,2,3])
```

However, your circuit seems to be a bit off: the resulting circuit of yours would be a Hadamard gate first, followed by a series of measurements, and **then** the initialization at the end.

To build the circuit as in your picture, this code will do:

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(4)

qc.initialize(psi, [0,1,2,3])

qc.h(0)

qc.measure_all()
```

The resulting circuit would be:
[image]